# MySQL Connection from an IoT Edge Module

Tags: c#, mysql, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I use my machine as a simulated device.

I deployed a docker image as a module to the device where I want to connect to a MySQL instance.

But I have the following error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

I build the connection like this:

```
public static MySqlConnection BuildConnection(MySqlProperties parameters)
{
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connString.Server = parameters.Server;
    connString.Database = parameters.Database;
    connString.UserID = parameters.Username;
    connString.Password = parameters.Password;
    connString.Add("Allow User Variables", true);

    var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString.ToString());
    return connection;
}
```

and then execute

```
var conn = BuildConnection(props);
Console.WriteLine("opening connection to mysql ...");
conn.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connection state: " + conn.State);
```

Is it possible to connect to that database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that MySQL wasn't configured for remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to get deep in this topic. As far as my understandings are, this error is expected, because you have to install the MySQL server as a module on the Edge run-time.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-store-data-sql-server) Microsoft documentation provides instructions on storing data on the Edge with SQL Server. It is written that the same should work for MySQL, as well.

Comment: The MySQL server (or any other remote server you want to connect to from your modules), does not need to run as part of IoT Edge. It can, of course, but doesn't have to.